# Pass through authentication in Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Can we use pass through authentication in Azure B2C. If no, What could be the best way to authenticate the existing user against On Premises LDAP server.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to federate with something like ADFS 2016 / 2019 that can authenticate against LDAP as long as it is V3 compliant.

Or use a SaaS IDP e.g Auth0 / Okta that can authenticate against LDAP.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom) to connect with on-premises LDAP. You can follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-adfs2016-idp) link to connect ADFS with Azure AD B2C.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion